# Get selected text within an text item in Oracle forms

Tags: oracleforms

There is following scenario: 
In Oracle Forms 10, there is a TextItem with text in it. User selects a part of the text using his mouse or keyboard and presses a forms button with trigger behind it.

**How do I find the portion of the text selected by the user?**

In VisualBasic, there is something like SelectionStart, SelectionEnd, SelectionText. What is the equivalent in forms? Is there any chance to do it with WebUtil?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 built-ins in Oracle form for handling this sort of thing:

```
COPY_REGION
CUT_REGION
PASTE_REGION
```

They are all restricted built-ins, so you need to be choosy about which trigger you call them in.  Refer to the documentation, it will tell you whether restricted built ins are allowed or not in that particular trigger.

They take no parameters, only operating on the currently selected item (see `:system.cursor_item`).  So, the user is in "textfield1" and they select a certain portion of the data.  You need to decide which trigger to issue `COPY_REGION` in (the easy one is `KEY-NEXT-ITEM`).  For your example, when the user would then press the button to copy, your code would navigate to the intented TextItem and issue the `PASTE_REGION` built-in.